# System of help for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide, android-studio

this is my first time with Android Studio and I can remember when you try to use button functions eclipse shows the functions available and text of description, but Android Studio no...
For example: button.setOnClickListener().... 
This system of help it's available in Android Studio?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean suggestions?
Check if `CTRL + Space bar` is what you are looking for as these stand for suggestion by default. Please notice Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, so all IDEA's shortcuts should work in AS as well.[Read more about code assistance here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_assistance.html).

By the way - you can set your shortcuts to be Eclipse-like.
You may also want to read [FAQ for Eclipse Users](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html)

Edit.
Ah, I posted so many link already, I'll post one more: [Default shortcuts keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)